# Nanoc3 site creation estimation

Tags: ruby, content-management-system, estimation

I am asked to create a few small websites using nanoc3 like http://www.pancakeaircompressor.org/, how long does it take? I am quite familiar with Ruby & HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will take you a day or two for one small website like that, provided you are very familiar with Ruby & HTML.